# summation of 2 select statements throught SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add all the first results (cou_code) to the second results (cou_code) by using a variable in SQL

```
select count(cou_code) as changes, state_code from sdrp15_submission_log sl
     where  state_code in (select distinct state_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                           where  state_code = sl.state_code
                           and    cou_code  != 'All')
     and   qa_date  is null
     and   phase = 'A'                      
     group by state_code;
```

Produces the result:

```
    CHANGES STATE_CODE

---------- ----------
        29 01        
         2 16        
         2 02        
         1 05        
         3 06
```

-- changes All

```
 select count(cou_code), st_code
 from   sdrp15_cosd
 where  st_code = (select distinct state_code 
                    from sdrp15_submission_log
                    where  state_code = st_code
                    and    cou_code   = 'All'
                    and    phase = 'A'
                    and    qa_date is null)
 and   phase = 'A'
 group by st_code;
```

produces the result:

```
COUNT(COU_CODE) ST_CODE
--------------- -------
            157 01     
              1 11     
            180 16     
             61 02     
           1088 06
```

Comment: did you forget the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sum the `count`s from the queries this is one way to do it using `cte`s.

```
with x as (
select count(cou_code) as changes, state_code from sdrp15_submission_log sl
where  state_code in (select distinct state_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                       where  state_code = sl.state_code
                       and    cou_code  != 'All')
and   qa_date  is null
and   phase = 'A'                      
group by state_code)
, y as (select count(cou_code) as cnt, st_code
from   sdrp15_cosd
where  st_code = (select distinct state_code 
                from sdrp15_submission_log
                where  state_code = st_code
                and    cou_code   = 'All'
                and    phase = 'A'
                and    qa_date is null)
and   phase = 'A'
group by st_code)
select x.state_code, x.changes+y.cnt
from x join y on x.state_code = t.st_code
```